# Salesforce Case custom field

Tags: case

I have a custom form and multiple fields. Is it possible to add a custom fields when creating and submitting new case using REST api?

Comment: is your question can you populate the Case object custom fields with new values or do you want to dynamically create new custom fields not previously part of the Case object?

Answer (score 0):

The [Force.com Tooling API Developer's Guide](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_toolingpre/api_tooling.pdf) says you can add custom fields to *custom* objects.

If your calling code will Apex, the simplest solution would be to use Andrew Fawcett's [Apex Wrapper for the Salesforce Metadata API](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi).  The documentation page has an example for adding a custom field.

You can use [Workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com) for testing your REST calls.

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention I want to use the salesforce REST api.

Comment: Are you asking how to add the fields to the custom form, or to the case object itself using REST?

Comment: to the case object using REST